# How to Load a dll file in SSIS That ins't in the GAC

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to load a dll in a SSIS project that ins't in a GAC. I followed the following code from [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/)

**the code:**

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
     static ScriptMain()
     {
         AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
     }
     static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
     {
         if (args.Name.Contains("ssisHelper"))
         {
             string path = @"c:\temp\";
             return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "ssisHelper.dll"));
         }
         return null;
     }
}
```

This enabled the loading of the dll but it keep giving me the following error because Entity Framework was referenced inside the dll.

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I tried to set the Working directory of dll with no success because dll's don't have an entry point. So I got the idea to put the file in a console application from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577567/can-a-c-sharp-dll-assembly-contain-an-entry-point). I built an .exe and changed it to a .dll. Now in theory I have an entry point where I could set the working directory.

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"PathToDll";
```

Yet I still get the same error. Does any one know of a solution?

Comment: That code you've got there for telling SSIS that anything with "ssisHelper" in the name should be loaded from C:\Temp\? It should work just as well for Entity Framework, or any other assembly you'd wanted to load.

Comment: @JeroenMostert How do I change it so I can load Multiple assembly's? Do you have an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an else if clause for each Assembly name:

```
static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Name.Contains("ssisHelper"))
            {
            string path = @"c:\temp\";
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "ssisHelper.dll"));

        }
        else if (args.Name.Contains("xxx"))
             {
            string path = @"c:\temp\";
            return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "xxx.dll"));


        };    return null;
```

Comment: Thanks I actually did stumbled over this on Friday. But this is correct. Do you have any Idea how to connect to the config file from the dll. Im getting a connection string error. I also need other configuration settings to be accessible.

Comment: Which configuration file? Tip : dont forget to add provider to the connectionstring

Comment: SSIS is load a dll that that connects to a database. The dll file uses a config file with the connection string in it. However when its loaded into SSIS its not loading that config file so I get a connection string error.

Comment: Is this dll made by you? Do you have source code? If yes you must modify the function to pass connectionstring as a parameter. If not i dont think you can modify dll from ssis so it recommended to update your question and write that problem. Or mark it as answered and ask a new question. So your question will be visible to other users.