# Is it possible to have the program entry point in a library assembly?

Tags: c#, .net

In compiled system languages (like C/C++), generally, the entry point is resolved at link time, which gives the ability to have the `main` function in a DLL so the linker won't complain and set the entry point address to the symbol in the DLL (or the function in the import library, not sure about that).

I recently started using C# and I would like to do something similar, where I have the `Main` method in a library (which preferably build against .NET Standard) and the actual exe don't define any entry point and uses the one in the library.

I get that I could just write a `Main` method in the exe and call the `Main` of the library in it, but the point is that I would like to avoid that.

I believe Winforms and WPF provide something similar, so hopefully what I'm trying to do is possible, otherwise, please educate me on the reasons why .NET doesn't provide such mechanism.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9577595/5509738) might work for you or [ModuleInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.moduleinitializerattribute?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @KarenPayne I tried your first option but it just don't work. I can't specify in the executable project that I want to use the `Main` in the library, and if I don't specify any the compiler give me an error telling that the app don't contain an entry point.  
Using `ModuleInitializer`, would I be able to set the entrypoint at runtime ? Like something related to `App_Domain` ?

Comment: `would I be able to set the entrypoint at runtime` No

Comment: @KarenPayne I meant, setting what method will be called first instead of the actual entry point of the program, since `ModuleInitializer` seems to let you execute code before the specified entry point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here:

In .NET, the only difference between a DLL and an EXE is purely the presence of `.entrypoint` in the header, which identifies the starting method that the CLR bootstrapper calls.

If there isn't one then it's a library rather than an application. It makes no sense to have an EXE which has no `.entrypoint` on any method, it won't run because the CLR bootstrapper won't know what to do with it.

Winforms and WPF do not do what you claim: they have a normal `.entrypoint`, it just happens to be boiler plate code which you don't need to worry about.

For clarity: the actual extension of the file is somewhat irrelevant. It's perfectly legal to call an assembly whatever you want, and you can link an assembly containing `.entrypoint` within another one, whether or not it has `.exe` extension or any other.

However, Windows will only bootstrap a file automatically if it has the `.exe` extension, as the CLR bootstrapper itself needs bootstrapping. You can though call `AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly` which essentially does the same thing from within another app.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Then, if I understand correctly, it is not possible to specify an assembly `.entrypoint` to point to a method in another assembly , as it have to be local to the building assembly; what I'm trying to do is basically impossible.

Comment: Correct. It is however theoretically possible to split a single assembly into separate modules (files) however they function as a single assembly and must be compiled together. I'm not sure how that behaves if the `.exe` does not have the `.entrypoint`, but difficult to test as I don't think Visual Studio can compile that way. You could try it with ILAsm. See also ECMA-335 specification, section I.15.4.1.2